# Banco de dados não funcional PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, formulário, phpmyadmin

Tenho um formulário PHP com um banco de dados MySQL gerado pelo phpMyAdmin, porém, o banco não recebe as informações inseridas no formulário.

**Segue o código do formulário:**

```html
<!-- content -->
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h1 style="
                    margin-top:100px;">Cadastro de Formações</h1>
                <p> </p>
                <p class="lead"></p>
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <form id="cadastro" name="cadastro" method="post" style="
                        text-align: left;
                        margin-top:50px;">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="form-group" style="
                        text-align: left;">
                                <label  for="NOME">Nome: </label>
                                <input  type="text" class="form-control" id="NOME" placeholder="Nome da formação">
                             </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="form-group" method="post" style="
                        text-align: left;">
                                <label  for="CARGA">Carga Horária: </label>
                                <input  type="text" class="form-control" id="CARGA" placeholder="Carga horária da formação">
                             </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="form-group" method="post" style="
                        text-align: left;">
                                <label  for="OBJETIVO">Objetivo: </label>
                                <input  type="text" class="form-control" id="OBJETIVO" placeholder="Objetivo da formação">
                             </div>
                             <div class="form-group" method="post" style="
                        text-align: left;">
                                <label for="CONTEUDO">Conteúdo da programático: </label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" id="CONTEUDO" rows="3" placeholder="Conteúdo programático da formação"></textarea>
                             </div>
                             <div class="">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Salvar</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                     </form>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
```

**Segue abaixo a conexão, em uma outra página, conecta.php:**

```
  <?php
    include("conecta.php");
    $conn = new mysqli ("localhost", "root", "", "db_formacoes");

    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $objetivo = $_POST['objetivo'];
    $conteudo = $_POST['conteudo'];
    $carga = $_POST['carga'];

     $query = "INSERT INTO formacoes (nome,objetivo,conteudo,carga)  VALUES('$nome','$objetivo','$conteudo', '$carga')";

    $resultado = mysqli_query($conn,$squery);

    if(!mysqli_query($conn, $squery)){  
        echo 'Opa, não conseguimos nos conectar ao banco de dados. '. mysqli_error($conn);
    }else{
        echo 'Operação realizada com sucesso';
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Salvo com Sucesso !");
    window.history.go(-1);
</script>
```

**Além de não salvar, não aparece nada na tela, nem mesmo os alerts em JS que fiz. Segue os alerts:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validaCampo()
    {
    if(document.cadastro.nome.value=="")
        {
        alert("O Campo nome é obrigatório!");
        return false;
        }
    }
    else 
        if(document.cadastro.carga.value=="");
        {
            alert("O campo carga horária é obrigatório!");
            return false;
        }
    else 
        if(document.cadastro.objetivo.value=="");
        {
            alert("O campo objetivo é obrigatório");
            return false;
        }
    else
        if(document.cadastro.conteudo.value=="");
        {
            alert("O campo conteúdo da formação é obrigatório!");
            return false;
        }
    else
        return true;
    </script>
```

**Quando clico pra salvar aparece que foi salvo, mas quando verifico o banco não tem nenhum registro. [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
**Se alguém puder me indicar o problema e como resolver, desde já agradeço.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ocorre que quando você omite o valor de `action` o processamento ocorre na mesma página.

No seu caso o problema são os atributos `name` dos campos.

Quando você usa `$nome = $_POST['nome'];` esse valor contido dentro do `$_POST` refere-se ao `name` do campo, então seu input deve ter um atributo chamado `name` com o valor apropriado... Por exemplo :

`<input  type="text" class="form-control" id="NOME" name="nome" placeholder="Nome da formação">`

Altere seus inputs, colocando o `name` com o respectivo valor que está sendo recebido por `$_POST['name_do_campo`]`.

Em relação ao action omitido em seu form,  existem algumas formas para processamento na mesma página, sendo:

Deixar em branco: `"action=""`...

Ou pode usar `action="<?PHP echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"`...

Outra falha encontra-se em sua `query`...

`$query = "INSERT INTO formacoes VALUES('$nome','$objetivo','$conteudo', '$carga' )";`

Você precisa informar as colunas e os valores respectivos em sua `query`, vou assumir para as colunas os mesmos nomes das varáveis, mas você deve conferir, ficaria assim:

`$query = "INSERT INTO formacoes (nome,objetivo,conteudo,carga)  VALUES('$nome','$objetivo','$conteudo', '$carga' )";`

Comment: Opa, agora o formulário está recebendo as informações certinho, posso ver isso através de um var_dump. Agora o único problema é o banco que não está registrando.

Comment: Complementei a resposta. Boa Sorte, caso alguma das respostas estiver correta considere validá-la clicando no icon verde abaixo as setas de avaliação da resposta.

Comment: Fiz as alterações sugeridas além de passar a conexão pra uma página "conecta.php" onde eu coloquei um h1 escrito salvo com sucesso. Mas dá o seguinte erro que eu vou editar.

Comment: Olha somente pela imagem fica difícil, o que eu consigo ver é que o código está duplicado em seu editor, tente postar o código aqui exatamente igual ao que está no seu editor...

Comment: Não acho necessário... Pode editar essa mesmo...

Comment: Prontinho, editado. :)

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62722/discussion-between-magichat-and-mariana-ferreira).

Answer (score 1):

Você não colocou a `action` no seu `form`.

Isso:

```
 <form id="cadastro" name="cadastro" method="post" style="
                text-align: left;
                margin-top:50px;">
```

Tem que ser isso:

```
 <form id="cadastro" name="cadastro" method="post" action="minhapage.php" style="
                text-align: left;
                margin-top:50px;">
```

Aproveitando:
O seu `button`Tem que ser do tipo `submit`

```
                         <div class="">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Salvar</button>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Nesse action tem que ter o arquivo dessa página do formulário?

Comment: o action aponta pra página que tem o código php que faz a inserção no bd

Comment: Então eu teria que separar a conexão da página do formulário?

Comment: Opa, agora o formulário tá recebendo os valores certinho. Posso ver isso através de um var_Dump.

Comment: Coloque um $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); para verificar se há algum erro no seu PHP. Se bem que você tá usando uma forma de PHP anterior a versão desta sintaxe....

Comment: Então, eu tentei separar a parte php da mesma página do formulário pra, na hora do action, redirecionar pra outra página e não pra mesma. O prbolema é que tá dando um erro no apache pra carregar a página.

Comment: depois que ele salva, coloca um header pra redirecionar pra outra página. Já que a página que salva não tem código em html.

Comment: Então, eu passei a conexão pra um arquivo separado conecta.php e nele coloquei um h1 com um texto qualquer. Mas dá o seguinte erro que eu vou editar.