# Formulário não recebe dados cadastrados

Tags: php, javascript, banco-de-dados, formulário, phpmyadmin

**O que está acontecendo:**

Tenho um sistema que, ao terminar de preencher o formulário e salvar, não salva as alterações aparecendo um `alert` de "salvo sem alterações" e voltando pra página anterior.

Não parece ser um problema de conexão com o banco nem do banco em si, mas do formulário que não reconhece quando algum campo foi alterado.

**Segue parte do formulário:**

```
    <?php
    // Busca valores no banco de dados para preenchimento do formulário que quer alterar.
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $sql = (" SELECT * FROM r WHERE id = '{$id}'");
    $query=mysql_query($sql);
    while ($campo = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {  
    ?>

    <div class="container">
        <form method="post" action="../std/update.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="r" class="formulario">
            <div class="container container-divisor">
                <h4>Descrição R</h4>
                <div class="row">
                    <input type="hidden" name="idnovo" id="idnovo" value="<?=$campo['id'];?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="dataedicao" id="dataedicao" value="<?php echo date('d/m/Y'); ?>">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label for="datacriacao">Data</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="datacriacao" id="dataCriacao" value="<?=$campo['datacriacao'];?>"127>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

**Conexão com o banco:**

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("erro na conexao com o banco de dados!");
    mysql_select_db("db_r");
?>
```

**Atualização no banco:**

```
<?php 
include ("conecta.php");

    $id             =   $_POST["idnovo"]; 
    $dataedicao     =   $_POST["dataedicao"];
    $datacriacao    =   $_POST["datacriacao"];
    $statusgeral    =   $_POST["statusgeral"];

// Inserir dados no banco
    $itens = $_POST['m'];
//$_POST['m'] as $itens
    if (!empty($itens)){
 $itens = implode(',', $_POST['m']);
}

   $up= ("UPDATE r SET dataedicao = '$dataedicao', datacriacao = '$datacriacao', statusgeral = '$statusgeral', criadopor = '$criadopor', origem = '$origem', projet = '$projet', jalon = 'jalon', domaine = '$domaine', classification = '$classification', link = '$link', themes = '$themes', description = '$description',conseil = '$conseil', recidiv = '$recidiv', priorite = '$priorite', pilote = '$pilote', itens = '$itens', refstandard = '$refstandard', titre = '$titre', modif = '$modif', respect = '$respect', pourquoi = '$pourquoi', dataplan1 = '$dataplan1', action1 = '$action1', pilote1 = '$pilote1', metierp1 = '$metierp1', dateprevu1 = '$dateprevu1', datereal1 = '$datereal1', status1 = '$status1', link1 = '$link1', type1 = '$type1', datacomm1 = '$datacomm1', commentaire1 = '$commentaire1', suivre = '$suivre', dataplan2 = '$dataplan2', action2 = '$action2', altis2 = '$altis2', pilote2 = '$pilote2', metierp2 = '$metierp2', dateprevu2 = '$dateprevu2', datereal2 = '$datereal2', status2 = '$status2', link2 = '$link2', type2 = '$type2', datacomm2 = '$datacomm2', commentaire2 = '$commentaire2' WHERE id = '$id' ;");

$up= mysql_query($up) or die(mysql_error());




?>
    <?php
    if (mysql_affected_rows() > 0) { 
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
            alert("Salvo com Sucesso !");
            window.history.go(-1);
        </script>';    
    } else {    
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
            alert("Salvo sem Modificações !");
            window.history.go(-1);
        </script>';
    }
?>
<?php           
    mysql_close($conexao);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**O alert:** 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
As informações alteradas no formulário não estão sendo salvas no banco, procurei muito por um erro mas até agora nada. 
Se puderem me apontar o erro ou sugerir algo, agradeceria.

**ATUALIZAÇÃO:**

O problema ainda não foi resolvido, porém dei um `echo` em `$up` e percebi que o formulário não está com nenhum problema, uma vez que são printadas na tela todas as informações alteradas. Mas ainda assim essas informações não estão sendo salvas no banco, então o problema deve estar na Update. 
Outra coisa que está sendo printada é o erro: "Coluna desconhecida em field list"

Comment: Atualizei a resposta. Espero que ajude.

Comment: Você está usando funções do tipo `mysql_` sugiro ler isso: [Porque não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%C3%A3o-devemos-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-tipo-mysql)

Comment: Na versão 5.5 do PHP essas funções já estão descontinuadas, e no PHP 7 elas nem funcionam mais.

Comment: @Knautiluz Eu troquei tudo pra mysqli_, mas depois refiz com mysql_ porque acho que o sistema dela está completamente em mysql_, então seria muita trabalheira. mysql_ funciona bem ainda no Php 5.6

Comment: A minha versão do php é bem antiga e muitos sistemas aqui usam essa versão. Não tenho permissão para atualizar, então não dá pra usar mysqli. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá. Eu notei duas coisas aí no seu código.

**A primeira é a linha:** `//$up = mysql_query("UPDATE retex SET dataedicao`(...)

Essa linha está de fato comentada? Experimente remover o "//", pois isso indica um comentário, logo, o interpretador ignora a instrução, e é justo essa a instrução para gravar as alterações no banco (não é?).

**Segunda coisa que notei é neste trecho:**

```
<?php
    if(mysql_affected_rows() > 0){
    ?>  
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Salvo com Sucesso !");
    window.history.go(-1);
</script>
<?php
        }
        else{
?>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Salvo sem Modificações !");
    window.history.go(-1);
</script>
```

Note que as tags `script` estão fora dos blocos Php, logo, elas serão printadas (echo) de qualquer maneira. Sendo assim, tanto o primeiro, quanto o segundo bloco de scripts estarão presentes no arquivo final que será enviado ao navegador. 
Portanto, experimente mudar para:

```
<?php
    if (mysql_affected_rows() > 0) { 
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
            alert("Salvo com Sucesso !");
            window.history.go(-1);
        </script>';    
    } else {    
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
            alert("Salvo sem Modificações !");
            window.history.go(-1);
        </script>';
    }
?>
```

Outro detalhe: feche as tags `input` com `/>` ao invés de só `>`. Sei que os browers mais modernos ignoram, mas é interessante testar para ver.

**UPDATE:** notei mais duas coisas.

*Primeira:* a variável `$statusgeral` não está preenchida, certo? Parece que o `$_POST['statusgeral']` não existe, já que não tem esse campo no formulário.

*Segunda coisa:* o fechamento do `input text` está `127>`, mude para somente `>`. Isso pode estar bugando o formulário.

### UPDATE 2

Eu repliquei a aplicação aqui e funcionou perfeitamente com pequenas alterações que fiz. O código está comentado mas, tendo qualquer dúvida, é só falar.

**conecta.php:** sem alterações aqui

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("erro na conexao com o banco de dados!");
mysql_select_db("db_r");
```

**Página do formulário:**

```
<?php
    // Busca valores no banco de dados para preenchimento do formulário que quer alterar.
    // Mudei include para require
    require 'conecta.php';
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM r WHERE id = '{$id}'";
    $query = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());   
 ?>

<div class="container">
<!-- Iniciei o "while loop" aqui embaixo.
OBS: corrija o URL da action="" para o seu URL. Eu mudei pois fiz tudo em uma só pasta -->
<?php while ($campo = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) : ?>
<form method="post" action="./update.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="r" class="formulario">
    <div class="container container-divisor">
        <h4>Descrição R</h4>
        <div class="row">
            <input type="hidden" name="idnovo" id="idnovo" value="<?=$campo['id'];?>">
             <!--  Alterei o value do dataedicao para o formate Ano/Mes/Dia Hora:minutos:segundos (timestamp). -->
            <input type="hidden" name="dataedicao" id="dataedicao" value="<?= date("Y/m/d H:i:s") ?>">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label for="datacriacao">Data</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="datacriacao" id="dataCriacao" value="<?=$campo['datacriacao'];?>"127>
                <!-- inseri um botão para enviar o formulário, uma vez que não sei como você está fazendo para enviá-lo -->
                    <input type="submit" value="enviar" id="send" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

**Update.php**

```
<?php 
// Mudei o include para require
require 'conecta.php';

// tudo igual por aqui, apenas atribui um valor qualquer à variável $statusgeral
$id             =   $_POST["idnovo"]; 
$dataedicao     =   $_POST["dataedicao"];
$datacriacao    =   $_POST["datacriacao"];
$statusgeral    =   'ativo';

// Montei o texto da query fora do mysql_query e alterei tudo para o formato '{$campo}', ao invés de só '$campo'    
$qr = "UPDATE retex SET dataedicao = '{$dataedicao}', datacriacao = '{$datacriacao}', statusgeral = '{$statusgeral}' WHERE id = '{$id}' ";
$qr = mysql_query($qr) or die(mysql_error());

// Verifica se foram atualizados os dados e printa na tela 
if (mysql_affected_rows() > 0):
    echo "Atualizado";
else:
    echo "Nada foi atualizado";
endif;
```

OBS: como o id está sendo passado via GET, é importante lembrar que você precisa informá-lo na URL. Me ocorreu que talvez esteja esquecendo isso.
Fica assim: http://localhost/paginadeatualizar/?id=numeroDoId

### **Update 3**

```
$up= "UPDATE r SET dataedicao = '$dataedicao', datacriacao = '$datacriacao', statusgeral = '$statusgeral', criadopor = '$criadopor', origem = '$origem', projet = '$projet', jalon = 'jalon', domaine = '$domaine', classification = '$classification', link = '$link', themes = '$themes', description = '$description',conseil = '$conseil', recidiv = '$recidiv', priorite = '$priorite', pilote = '$pilote', itens = '$itens', refstandard = '$refstandard', titre = '$titre', modif = '$modif', respect = '$respect', pourquoi = '$pourquoi', dataplan1 = '$dataplan1', action1 = '$action1', pilote1 = '$pilote1', metierp1 = '$metierp1', dateprevu1 = '$dateprevu1', datereal1 = '$datereal1', status1 = '$status1', link1 = '$link1', type1 = '$type1', datacomm1 = '$datacomm1', commentaire1 = '$commentaire1', suivre = '$suivre', dataplan2 = '$dataplan2', action2 = '$action2', altis2 = '$altis2', pilote2 = '$pilote2', metierp2 = '$metierp2', dateprevu2 = '$dateprevu2', datereal2 = '$datereal2', status2 = '$status2', link2 = '$link2', type2 = '$type2', datacomm2 = '$datacomm2', commentaire2 = '$commentaire2' WHERE id = '$id'";
```

Comment: Obrigada por responder a esta pergunta! A linha comentada só está comentada na pergunta, foi um erro na hora de colar o código, vou editar. A questão dos scripts era mesmo uma dúvida que eu tinha, vou fazer como sugeriu e retorno. :)

Comment: Então, eu editei com o resultado.

Comment: Mariana, como você está enviando o formulário? Eu não vi nenhum botão para enviar (tipo submit) ou mesmo button. Talvez não esteja gravando porque não está recebendo os dados.

Comment: Tire também a última vírgula antes do "WHERE" na sua query.

Comment: Então, o formulário está sendo enviado através de um botão submit normal.

Comment: Removi, mas ainda do mesmo jeito. :/

Comment: Ok. Também não estou entendendo. Vou analisar melhor isso.

Comment: Atualizei a resposta. Caso não seja isso, vou replicar a aplicação aqui e ver o resultado depois, pois agora não tenho tempo. Preciso sair.

Comment: A variável statusgeral existe. É que esse formulário na verdade é bem grande, mas por normas de confidencialidade não pude colocar todas os campos nessa pergunta. Mas nada relevante, é a mesma coisa desses três campos colocados na pergunta. Tudo bem, já ajudou muito, aguardo sua resposta. :)

Comment: Fiz as alterações sugeridas porém o formulário não funciona mais. :/

Comment: Testei alteração por alteração da página do formulário. Desde a primeira não funciona.

Comment: Quanto as alterações feitas na página update, ao salvar é printado na tela: Coluna 'conseil' desconhecida em 'field list', realmente existe na tabela uma coluna chamada conseil

Comment: @MarianaFerreira Mas você alterou o nome da tabela? Note que eu fiz tudo em uma só tabela, a tabela "r". Para voltar ao normal, você precisa mudar para "retex" de novo. (é o que está na pergunta). Vou editar a resposta.

Comment: Sim, eu fiz isso.

Comment: O seu problema está complicado. Eu testei isso aqui na versão 5.6 do Php, com banco Mysql e foi tudo normal. Eu não coloquei coluna "conseil" no banco, pois ela não está na pergunta. Recomendo que quando for fazer uma pergunta, coloque o código completo. Não precisa colocar dados confidencias, você pode substituí-los. Como em produção de software há muito acoplamento de código, postar só uma parte pode dar uma visão errada do problema. Segundo o que você descreveu, eu fiz a mesma aplicação e deu certo, mas o problema pode não estar aí onde você pensa, Mariana.

Comment: Pronto, editei a pergunta com toda a query. Só em algumas variáveis dá esse erro e eu não entendo o porque, uma vez que todas estão iguais.

Comment: Atualizei. Apenas alterei a $up, pois estava com erro de sintaxe ali. Teste aí e vamos ver.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63274/discussion-between-mariana-ferreira-and-inova-pixel).

Comment: Obrigada pela correção! Infelizmente ta dando o mesmo erro. Desculpe estar sendo tão insistente, é que meu prazo pra resolver esse problema termina hoje. :/

Comment: Se quiserem dar um help nessa daqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/223600/banco-de-dados-n%C3%A3o-funcional-php-mysql

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/226529/dados-de-formul%C3%A1rio-n%C3%A3o-est%C3%A3o-sendo-cadastrados/226547?noredirect=1#comment463963_226547