# Dados de formulário não estão sendo cadastrados

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, formulário, phpmyadmin

Tenho um formulário escrito em php com conexão a um banco administrado pelo phpMyAdmin.

**O QUE DEVERIA ACONTECER:**

Os dados inseridos no formulário deveriam ser cadastrados aparecendo um `alert` de "salvo com sucesso" e voltando para a página anterior.

**O QUE ESTÁ ACONTECENDO:**
Ao tentar cadastrar, até redireciona pra página responsável por cadastrar e mostrar o `alert`, mas a página está em branco, não aparece nenhum `alert`, não volta pra página anterior e nem cadastra as informações no banco.

**FORMULÁRIO:**

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h1 style="
                    margin-top:100px;">Cadastro de Formações</h1>
                <p> </p>
                <p class="lead"></p>
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <form id="cadastro" name="cadastro" method="post" action="banco/updateF.php" style="
                        text-align: left;
                        margin-top:50px;">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="form-group" style="
                        text-align: left;">
                                <label  for="NOME">Nome: </label>
                                <input  type="text" required class="form-control" id="NOME" name="NOME" placeholder="Nome da formação">
                             </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="form-group" method="post" style="
                        text-align: left;">
                                <label  for="CARGA">Carga Horária: </label>
                                <input  type="text" required class="form-control" id="CARGA" name="CARGA" placeholder="Carga horária da formação">
                             </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="form-group" method="post" style="
                        text-align: left;">
                                <label  for="OBJETIVO">Objetivo: </label>
                                <input  type="text" required class="form-control" id="OBJETIVO" name="OBJETIVO" placeholder="Objetivo da formação">
                             </div>
                             <div class="form-group" method="post" style="
                        text-align: left;">
                                <label for="CONTEUDO">Conteúdo da programático: </label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" id="CONTEUDO" rows="3" name="CONTEUDO" placeholder="Conteúdo programático da formação"></textarea>
                             </div>
                             <div class="">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Salvar</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
                                <strong>Hey! </strong> Antes de realizar o cadastro, certifique-se de que não se esqueceu de nada! :)
                            </div>
                        </div>
                     </form>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
```

**A CONEXÃO:**

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("erro na conexao com o banco de dados!");
    mysql_select_db("db_formacao");
?>
```

**O UPDATE:**

```
    <!-- Envia dados do formulario de edicao pro banco de dados -->

<!--TESTE DE BANCO -->

<?php 
require ("conecta.php");
//coletando dados do formulario

    $nome           =   $_POST["NOME"];
    $carga          =   $_POST["CARGA"];
    $objetivo       =   $_POST["OBJETIVO"];
    $conteudo       =   $_POST["CONTEUDO"];

// Inserir dados no banco
    $itens = $_POST['NOME'];

    if (!empty($itens)){
        $itens = implode(',', $_POST['NOME']);
    }
$up = "UPDATE turmas SET NOME = '$nome', CARGA = '$carga', OBJETIVO = '$objetivo', CONTEUDO = '$conteudo'";
echo $up;

$up= mysql_query($up) or die(mysql_error());

?>
<?php
    if (mysql_affected_rows() > 0) { 
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
            alert("Salvo com Sucesso !");
            window.history.go(-1);
        </script>';    
    } else {    
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
            alert("Salvo sem Modificações !");
            window.history.go(-1);
        </script>';
    }
?>
```

[image: Quando eu tento mostrar o código fonte pelo navegador só aparecem os comentários, mas a página da conexão não.]

**Quando tento exibir o código fonte dessa página em branco pelo navegador só aparecem os comentários da página update.**

Não sou muito experiente, mas pelo que eu estudei, não parece nada errado. 
Se puderem me indicar os erros, agradeceria bastante. :)

Comment: Qual a versão do php?

Comment: Isso é algo que eu esqueci de comentar. Minha versão do php é antiga e como tem muitos sistemas rodando nessa versão, eu não posso atualizar.

Comment: Mariana, por gentileza peço que não fique adicionando AJUDA no titulo, só o fato de ter perguntado no site já entendemos que precisa de ajuda com seu problema.

Comment: Ta, eu ia tirar depois de uns minutos.

Comment: Mas não pode fazer isso simplesmente com o objetivo de "upar" a pergunta. Caso as respostas não tenham resolvido o problema, comente abaixo delas. Ou edite a pergunta fornecendo mais detalhes. Pode também ler [ask] para saber como melhorar a pergunta.

Comment: Sim, mas já to fornecendo todos os detalhes, já comentei abaixo das respostas, to estudando, tentando resolver mas não encontro o problema e já fazem alguns dias. Sei que ninguém tem a obrigação de me responder, foi só uma tentativa, não precisa dar bronca.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nada estava errado com o formulário, o erro era no arquivo update.
Reformulei e resolveu assim:

```
<!--ENVIA OS DADOS DO FORMULÁRIO PARA O BANCO-->

<?php

    $nome = $_POST['NOME'];
    $carga = $_POST['CARGA'];
    $objetivo = $_POST['OBJETIVO'];
    $conteudo = $_POST['CONTEUDO'];

    $strcon = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','', 'db_formacao') or die('Erro ao conectar ao banco de dados');
    $sql = "INSERT INTO formacoes VALUES ('$id', '$nome', '$carga', '$objetivo', '$conteudo')"; 
    mysqli_query($strcon,$sql) or die("Erro ao tentar cadastrar registro");
    mysqli_close($strcon);

    echo "Formação cadastrada com sucesso!";
?>
```

Agradeço a todos que me ajudaram.

Answer (score 1):

Mariana, se você está enviando javascript para o navegador do cliente é necessário enviar o cabeçalho correto, no caso antes do seu `echo` faça isso :

```
header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
if (mysql_affected_rows() > 0) { 
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
        alert("Salvo com Sucesso !");
        window.history.go(-1);
    </script>';    
} else {    
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
        alert("Salvo sem Modificações !");
        window.history.go(-1);
    </script>';
}
```

No caso acima estou enviando ao navegador e avisando que o código de retorno do php é um javascript, para que ele interprete a rotina.

Atualização

```
  <?php 
       require ("conecta.php");
       //coletando dados do formulario
       $id             =   $_POST["ID"]; 
       $nome           =   $_POST["NOME"];
       $objetivo       =   $_POST["OBJETIVO"];
       $conteudo       =   $_POST["CONTEUDO"];
       $carga          =   $_POST["CARGA"];

       // Inserir dados no banco
       $itens = $_POST['NOME'];

       if (!empty($itens)){
           $itens = implode(',', $_POST['NOME']);
       }
       $up = "UPDATE formacoes SET NOME = '".$nome."', OBJETIVO = '".$objetivo."', 
       CONTEUDO = '".$conteudo."', CARGA = '".$carga."'  WHERE id =".$id;
       $up= mysql_query($up) or die(mysql_error());

       echo "Número de linhas afetadas:".mysql_affected_rows()."<br/>";
       if (mysql_affected_rows() > 0) { 
            $resposta = 'Update concluído com sucesso!';    
       } else{    
           $resposta = 'Cadastro não sofreu alterações!';   
       }
       mysql_close($conexao);
       die($resposta);
   ?>
```

Roda com esse script e me diz o que deu?

Comment: Então, até fiz, mas continua a mesma coisa. O engraçado é que esse mesmo update funciona em outro sistema.

Comment: Faça um teste assim que aparecer a página em banco com o botão direito mande exibir o código de fonte e verifique se tem o conteúdo do seu echo.

Comment: Então, não está mostrando o conteúdo, o que me leva a acreditar que talvez o problema seja no formulário. :/

Comment: Essa página php banco/updateF.php existe? Você está postando para ela, é esse mesmo o nome ? Se o form está online mande o endereço para que eu possa verificar.

Comment: Então, se trata de um sistema interno então não tá online. Mas essa página updateF.php existe sim, a página chega a ser redirecionada pra ela. Vou colocar uma imagem do que está acontecendo.

Comment: Então, rodei com esse script e deu a mesma coisa, nada novo aconteceu. :/

Comment: É, nada ainda. @RafaelSalomão

Answer (score 1):

Posso estar errado, mas pelo que vi no formulário de preenchimento dos dados, não tem a entrada para o ID, e no código PHP tanto na recuperação dos dados quanto na query de update você usa um id que não existe. Deu pra entender o que eu quis dizer?
Olha o código de novo e veja no formulário que não tem um campo para inserir o id, e no seu código php está assim:

```
   $id             =   $_POST["ID"]; //essa linha aqui não está recuperando nada
   $nome           =   $_POST["NOME"];
   $objetivo       =   $_POST["OBJETIVO"];
   $conteudo       =   $_POST["CONTEUDO"];
   $carga          =   $_POST["CARGA"];
```

Logo em seguida temos:

```
    $up = "UPDATE formacoes SET NOME = '$nome', OBJETIVO = '$objetivo', CONTEUDO = '$conteudo', CARGA = '$carga'  WHERE id = '$id'";
//nessa linha você está usando um id inexistente
```

Talvez seja por isso que o update não esteja sendo realizado. Confere aí e dá um feedback!

Comment: Muito bem notado CloudAC +1. Cadê o campo id para ser postado Mariana deveria ser um <input type='hidden' name='id' value='5'>

Comment: Nossa, isso faz muito sentido! Eu tinha colocado o ID porque existe um campo na tabela que é um ID auto increment então fiquei na dúvida se deveria colocar ou não.

Comment: Sim passei o olho e não notei, corrigi isso e vê se funciona e aproveita pega o código que montei abaixo e melhora o seu que está muito bagunçado a escrita.

Comment: Certo, fiz as alterações recomendadas. Deixa eu fazer uma pergunta: A minha formação tem um ID. Quando eu for cadastrar uma turma, vou precisar do ID da formação pra dizer que a turma pertence a aquela formação, certo? Outras formações vão ser cadastradas, então, eu não precisaria do Where pra dizer em qual formação os dados devem ser atualizados?

Comment: Mari melhor montar outra pergunta senão tira a coesão desse post. E ai já sabe os moderadores vem em cima! =P

Comment: Ah, certo, vou montar e coloco o link aqui, ok? :)